# NoMethodError: undefined method `assert_emails' in controller test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, ruby-on-rails-5

According to the [Rails documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/TestHelper.html#method-i-assert_emails), the method `assert_emails` allows to transform the syntax :

```
assert_difference ->{ ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.size }, +1 do
  post :method_that_should_send_email
end
```

to

```
assert_emails 1 do
  post :method_that_should_send_email
end
```

which I find much better, because I don't have to copy paste the long syntax every time.

However I get the following error in my controllers tests when using the above code:

`` NoMethodError: undefined method `assert_emails' ``

I assume this is because the method is only available in mailers tests.

Is there a way to make it available to controllers tests too? Is there a good reason why this is not available by default? Is there a better way to test that calling a specific route results in sending a email?

Thanks.

Answer (score 16):

I've just had the same problem when trying to use `assert_emails` in a regular test (not an `ActionMailer::TestCase`).

The helpers started working when I included `ActionMailer::TestHelper` to my test class.

```
class FooTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  include ActionMailer::TestHelper

  test '...' do
    assert_no_emails do
      # ...
    end
  end
end
```

I believe that should work in your controller tests as well.

Comment: This also works below a `Rspec.describe` line

Answer (score 1):

** Using deliver_later **

If someone is sending the emails using `deliver_later`, then he can test it using the below code

```
include ActionMailer::TestHelper

test 'test deliver later' do
  assert_enqueued_emails 1 do
    ---code which runs deliver later--
  end

# Check the mailer name
  enqueued_jobs.first[:args][1] = 'my_mailer_method'
end
```